# Issuse with refresh QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt5, reload, qwebview, qwebengineview

i try reload an html file that i created with plotly
with opening the app its loading but when i try to reload with a button
my app stop working

```
class Window1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(700, 350, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Data Downloader")
        self.UI()
        # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bs.jpg"))
    def UI(self):
        #self.plot_widget = QWebEngineView()
        self.dldata = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.dldata.move(250, 25)
        self.dldata.clicked.connect(self.chartshow)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.browser.move(1, 100)
        self.browser.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.browser.setFixedHeight(400)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"\ht.html")
        self.browser.load(url)
    def chartshow(self):
        while 1 :
          self.browser.reload()
          time.sleep(10)
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think there is something about qwidget or qmain window but I don't know how to fix that!

Comment: The while-loop will block all event processing and freeze the guide. Use a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) instead.

Comment: I Used Thread and even QTIMER but The main problem is i cant use reload on another function

Comment: What does "i cant use reload on another function" mean? Your example code will work fine with a timer (but not multi-threading). Create a QTimer with a 10 second interval in `__init__`, and connect its `timeout` signal to `self.browser.reload`. Then call `self.timer.start()` as appropriate.